# glob: find `folder` that are not inside `folder`

Tags: node.js, glob

Using https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

The task is to find all `node_modules` folders in the project tree, that are not inside other node_modules.

I tried: something like:

- `('**/node_modules/', {ignore: '**/node_modules/**/node_modules/'})`

This works but takes a few minutes (about 10) for my projects with ~10 subrojects.

I thought there might be quicker way? Any advice on this?

Comment: I would suggest dropping the glob and simply finding all the `node_modules` and not walking their contents. Do you not have a filesystem walker that could be told to report but not to enter a directory those basename is `node_modules`?

Comment: Yeah I keep in mind just walking through the directories with `readdir`, just thought more quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno, works works fine for me:

```
glob('**/node_modules/', {ignore: '**/node_modules/**/node_modules/'}, console.log)
// Output: null [ 'node_modules/' ]

//  or sync
glob.sync('**/node_modules/', {ignore: '**/node_modules/**/node_modules/'})
// => [ 'node_modules/' ]
```

What did you expect?

Comment: it take a few minutes (about 10) for my projects with ~10 subrojects. I thought there should be quicker way.